# When working with ASP.NET do we have access to all classes in the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, windows

Is this a subset of .NET or is it the complete framework? If it's a subset, what classes (namespaces) is ASP.NET composed of, and more importantly which ones is it not composed of? I noticed in the documentation that there are obviously namespaces that only apply to web applications and vice versa with windows applications, but are these still accessible in ASP.NET?

Is the limit of what ASP.NET is made of based on the restrictions we set or is it, like I mentioned earlier, only a piece of the .NET Framework?

From developing with WP7 there obviously were restrictions, therefore making it only of a subset of the .NET Framework (Compact). From what I can tell there is no reason why ASP.NET should have any limitations. Is this correct?

Comment: I dunno if you CAN use all of the namespaces (like System.Windows etc.), but I do know that there are a lot of namespaces not automatically included with a ASP.NET application (like the Drawing-namespace), that can be included later by the IDE/compiler, so that you can use these too with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET development requires full .NET library (not the client profile) so you'll virtually have access to all namespaces in the framework so no restrictions. On the other hand, even though you can access objects like `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, they won't be fully functional as there is no desktop application and a desktop to show the form on (though you can still use them for other purposes than displaying a form on the desktop).

As a side note, actually your hosting provider may restrict some features in the framework (an example here: http://faq.1and1.co.uk/scripting/asp_net/2.html) so you'll have to check with them.